# Submeter form e actualizar conteúdo de div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Tenho dois `select option` com distritos e concelhos. Através de JSON consigo filtrar os distritos com os concelhos só que agora quero fazer a pesquisa a base de dados.
Quero submeter o `form` com as duas escolhas e actualizar a `div` que apresenta o conteúdo com o resultado da pesquisa. Como poderei fazer que o JavaScript (especificamente jQuery) mostre o resultado corretamente?

Comment: O que queres com jQuery? Como é apresentada tua div?

Comment: eu tenho uma div que apresenta o conteúdo correspondente a categoria que o utilizador escolheu agora queria atraves de jquery nessa mesma pagina que o utilizador filtra-se por distrito e concelhos e quando clicar em procurar actualizada a div e mostra-se o conteúdo da consulta

Comment: Leia http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-integrate-live-search-in-php-and-mysql-with-jquery_309.html

Answer (score 1):

Você pode retornar um valor na pesquisa (mais especificamente, uma hash única e temporária). Crias um script que a retorna o resultado de pesquisa dessa hash em forma de array ou algo que o jQuery possa ler e depois de certo período de tempo faz a hash ser deletada. Assim, o sistema tem uma segurança mais alta e não faz interface direta cliente->base de dados.

Comment: Pode me dar um exemplo mais especifico dessa funcionalidade

Comment: @CésarSousa bem, não sou programador de PHP, nem sequer sei como funciona. Vou procurar na internet e respondê-lo de maneira mais completa.

Comment: Bem estive aqui a programar um pouco e já conseguir por a funcionar como eu queria, porém agora estou enfrentando um problema na pesquisa quando são distritos ou concelhos que tem acentos não me retorna nada

Comment: @CésarSousa isso se deve ao encoding. Tenta usar ASCII.

Comment: Mas eu imprimo o valor na tela e ele aparece bem

Comment: Exato. O enconding usado pelo MySql pode ser UTF-8. Posso estar errado, mas 90% dos casos se devem a isso.

Comment: O enconding no meu mysql sim esta em UTF-8 então para qual deveria mudar

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html